# Why they are allowed to use AdSense on breaking rules sites?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I've investigated many websites and found lots of them using AdSense against rules (**permanently without any penalties**). All of the rules violation I reference to [Google Ad placement policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295) and [AdSense program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en).

## Few basic examples:

- one of the biggest public transport search engine:

**Ads on dynamic content, [Ads] Placed on any non-content-based page** - Ad on left-bottom is in section without unique and quality content, in addition the result of transport search is dynamically created which is strictly prohibited.

- one of the most popular meme site:

**Displaying ads on website with no contextual content *is prohibited*** - many of sites without text content like flash games, images, videos etc. run google AdSense, which they should be banned for infringing rules.

- global leader in translations:

**No original and unique content** - this type of websites cannot have well prepared content because of it's purpose, why they are allowed to use AdSense so it's text is shredded and have no mutual meaning.

---

I've also run **non-blog site**, those Google **don't like for contextual ads**. Why then some of sites (even the biggest ones) are running AdSense without problem when I'm not allowed to do so?

Comment: I don't like the fact that you site real site examples.   While it makes your question concrete, calling out other sites for bad behavior publicly sounds petty.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I agree with you, sorry about that - I will censor those sites within a second. I won't hide that I'm emotionally involved in this topic, I do not see it's fair that's why I might be more oppressive than I want to, sorry.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. This type of question is better suited for [chat].

Comment: Try: https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/1190500

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have to straighten it out - _I don't want to report them, it gives me nothing and I have no problem with their ads_ - **I would like to use AdSense like those** because it is unfair in compare to my site.

Answer (score 1):

Without talking about the sites you specifically mention the tools Google uses to identify breaches of AdSense Ad placement policies are automated tools with some manual human searches. When you take into account the sheer number of sites running AdSense you start to see how enormous of a task this is. Because of this Google does provide a [web form](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/1190500?hl=en) for internet users to report violations of AdSense policy for Google to review if you feel that strongly about it.

The other thing to realise is that while the site in question may seem like it breaches the AdSense terms there are instances where it is a grey area as to if the site in question is breaching terms or not and so the decision really rests with Google and with them making the final decision. The only thing you can do as a webmaster is make sure to comply with the terms as written, there isn't much you can do regarding other sites and their ad placements.

Comment: You are right in every point - the problem here is how then they got approved in reality if they should be prohibited to use Google's ad service. And even if they were accepted with another site, why they are still "on air" if those ones are infringing rules. It's hard subject, in theory those types of sites never know when they would be banned.

Comment: And that is exactly the point, sites that blatantly flaunt AdSense policies are really trading on borrowed time and know that they could loose AdSense at any point so they simply keep going until if and when Google contacts them and says that their sites breach AdSense policies.

Comment: Probably that's the best answer to my problem - thank you for help, well.. it seems world is still about the trick.